# How to get images displayed on ArcGIS Online Popups

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, popup

I have added images to show up in an html popup on ArcMap, but when I bring it in to ArcGIS Online, they don't appear. Is there a way to get the images to show up there? Currently on ArcGIS Online the option offered only shows the same image for all the points.

[image: On Arcmap]

[image: ArcGIS Online]

Comment: Is the path to the image a local path? That is, if the image is stored locally on your machine, it's not going to be accessible on ArcGIS Online.

Comment: How do i get it to display different pictures? i did try to upload them on the server but no luck. it just shows <raster>

Answer (score 1):

What you'll have to do is host the pictures on an image hosting site, add a field to the table that you'll put the links to the pictures in. Then, in configure popup, at the bottom is a media section. Click Image, and change the Title field to list the name of the title field in your attribute table within these pointy brackets --->  {titleorwhatever}
for the url, do the same {http://urlgoeshere.com/picturethatisonlyjpgor.png}

this will put the picture at the bottom of the popup. I don't know if you can modify that to put it at the top or not. Also, good luck getting it to show up in a web app, cause I have had none.

Comment: using the same method described as above will work in web apps as well.  the main thing is you want to use the media section when you configure your popup attributes.  we created a related db to the main gdb and in the related db we had a field that held the http link, and loaded the pics from there